# Changing CSS Style Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the width of a bar when I click on the button; but it's not working. I have tried copying the code, replacing the ids and rewriting the code, but I don't know why it's not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8,IE=9" />
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var bar = document.getElementById("Bar");
            function load(){
                bar.style.width = "500px;";
            }
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type"text/css" href="Style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mainwrapper">
            Citadel goal
            <div id="Shell">
                <div id="Bar"></div>
            </div>
            <form><input type="button" value ="click" onclick="load();"/></form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i also have this as the css
#Shell{
padding:1px;
margin:5px auto;
background-color:#CC0000;
width:200px;
height:15px;
}
#Bar{
background-color:#AAF200;
width:200pxx;
height:15px;
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two issues:

1. You're trying to retrieve the `Bar` element before it exists, so your `bar` variable is `null`. Move the `getElementById` call **into** the `load` function, so you're not trying to get the element until after it exists.
2. The style value shouldn't have the `;` in it. E.g.:

   ```
   bar.style.width = "500px;";
   // Remove this ---------^
   ```

Working example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/kukeqaki/1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function load() {
            var bar = document.getElementById("Bar");
            bar.style.width = "500px";
        }
    </script>
    <!-- Your stylesheet was here, replaced with this since
         we don't have your stylesheet -->
    <style>
        #Bar {
            border: 1px solid #aaa;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainwrapper">
        Citadel goal
        <div id="Shell">
            <!-- Note: I added something to the div as otherwise it
                 had no height; presumably your stylesheet gives it height -->
            <div id="Bar">x</div>
        </div>

        <form>
            <input type="button" value="click" onclick="load();" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You function should be as this way;

```
function load(){
var bar = document.getElementById("Bar");
bar.style.width = "500px";
}
```

The reason is that initializing the property dosent know what does the `"bar"` contain if you does it outside the function so its better you always define it inside the fucntion.

Answer (score -1):

Initialize bar Variable in to the Load Method rather than outside.

```
function load() {
    document.getElementById("Bar").style.width = "500px";
}
```

try Above Code.